# will pen drive information same on both windows and Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, hardware, msdn

Greetings to all..

I have a pen drive which is a make of Trensend ....

Whether the product and vendor id of the above pen drive will be same on both windows and Mac operating systems..or will it be different ..

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of information is stored in the drive's firmware.  Different OSes might decide to make different random responses to that kind of information, but the information itself is constant.  The information doesn't care which kind of computer or OS it's being transmitted to.